# iOS view transitions using blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to switch from 3 views of same viewcontroller. I am reaching it properly but I always get a fade transition. I do not understand how exactly works. Which parameter defines type of transition? setType or layer forKey:? I tried both but I always get same effect! Thank you

```
CATransition *trans =[CATransition animation];
            trans.delegate = self;
            [trans setDuration:2];
            [trans setType:kCATransitionFromTop];
            [trans setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

        CALayer *layer = self.view.layer;

        [layer addAnimation:trans forKey:kCATransitionMoveIn];

        [self.view addSubview:vistaSocial];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transition between multiple views you can simply use the +transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: method of UIView. The options allow you to specify which type of transition you would like.

For example:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 toView:view2 duration:0.35 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html